# CodeIgniter project into another Codeigniter subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter Website (http://example.com)
I upload new beta version of website, I want to put it under /beta  so I can access it using(http://example.com/beta) 
in /beta I updated config.php :: $config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/beta"
when I try to access http://example.com/beta I get blank page, there is no error in log file
any idea or help please ? thanks!

Comment: Is the .htaccess allowing that directory be accessed? Has the .htaccess been updated in the beta directory? For example, you'll likely need to update the rewrite base to `RewriteBase /beta/`

Answer (score 1):

just upload your site in folder named "base" and keep yor $config['base_url'] =""; it will work fine

```
   -codeignitor

         -application

          -system

          -base

                 -application

                  -system

                   ......

           .....
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you very much
the problem was a kind of FTP foolishness
when I upload the project using FTP - FillZella, and everything went well!
but later I discover that  there is 2 files in CI core uploaded with 0 byte size! I don't know why although FillZila did not show any any any error message